# cannot find module '../app/models/user'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model-view-controller, oauth, passport.js

im struggled with this problem like more then 40 hours and sill don't know how to solve this, the problem is a little big to explain but i will try my best, im a little newbie with Node.Js and mongo stuffs so forgive me any stupid mistake.

I followed the book **Mean Stack** and the problem appears when i started [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) tutorial to do the autentication with auth, i am at the beginning doing the local authentication without any social at the moment.

**folder structure**

[image: folder structure]

**so basicly i set the server like this:**

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var mongoose = require('./config/mongoose');
var express = require('./config/express');


var db = mongoose();
var app = express();
app.listen(3000);

module.exports = app;

console.log("running at port 3000");
```

**this is the ./config/mongoose**

```
var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/ShareIdea"

module.exports = function(){
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connect(connectionString);

require('../app/models/user.server.model');

return db;
```

};

**the required user.server model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
    },
    facebook         : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    },
    twitter          : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        displayName  : String,
        username     : String
    },
    google           : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    }
    /*firstname:String,
    lastname:String,
    email:String,
    username:String,
    password:String,
    userChoice: {type: String, possibleValues: ['programmer','inovator']}*/
});

UserSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

UserSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

**here is the express configuration**

```
var config          = require('./config');
var express         = require('express');
var passport        = require('passport');
var flash           = require('connect-flash');
var compress        = require('compression');
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
var session         = require('express-session');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var morgan          = require('morgan');
var methodOverride  = require('method-override');
var expressLayouts  = require('express-ejs-layouts');

module.exports = function(){
    var app = express();

    **require('./passport')(passport);**

    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
    {
        app.use(morgan('dev'));
    }  
    else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
    {
        app.use(compress());

    }
    app.use(cookieParser());

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
       extended:true 
    }));
    app.use(morgan('dev'));

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(methodOverride());

    app.use(session({
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: true,
        secret: 'aaaaaaa'
    }));



    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
    app.use(flash());

    app.set('views', './app/views');
    app.set('view engine','ejs');
    app.use(expressLayouts);



    require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app,passport);
    require('../app/routes/register.server.routes.js')(app,passport);
    require('../app/routes/login.server.routes.js')(app,passport);
    require('../app/routes/profile.server.routes.js')(app,passport);
    app.use(express.static('./public'));
    return app;
}
```

here in the express is where the problems appear, this line is the main problem at the moment: `require('./passport')(passport);

if i put this code it gives me the problem that i mentioned in the title, if not when i do a POST request with my form it never posts, i have this troubles because i set the structures of my code to a MVC structure like the book and want to adapt the authentication in the tutorial to my code to learn a little,

**so basicly im passing the passport to my routes like this:`**

**register route**

```
var register = require('../../app/controllers/register.server.controller');

module.exports = function(app,passport) {
 app.route('/register')
 .post(function(req,res){
     console.log("HY");
      passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/register', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
  })})
 .get(register.getPage);
};
```

**Register controller**

```
var User = require('mongoose').model('User');

module.exports = {

  getPage: function(req,res){
      res.render('./pages/register',{ message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
  }

};
```

**and to end here is the passport code:**

```
// config/passport.js

// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// load up the user model
var User            = require('../app/models/user');

// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {

    // =========================================================================
    // passport session setup ==================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // required for persistent login sessions
    // passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    // =========================================================================
    // LOCAL SIGNUP ============================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
    // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {

        // asynchronous
        // User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back
        process.nextTick(function() {

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // check to see if theres already a user with that email
            if (user) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
            } else {

                // if there is no user with that email
                // create the user
                var newUser            = new User();

                // set the user's local credentials
                newUser.local.email    = email;
                newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

                // save the user
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }

        });    

        });

    }));

};
```

Ps: Sorry for the long post, i hope i can get a explanation since i want to learn more, when i read the book i felt like the mvc structure adapted by the autor was dificult, but anyways thanks a lot.

if you guys want to not look at this i understand and here is the gitProject:[git project](https://github.com/FilipeCosta/MeanStackBook)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your user.server.model.js file. Instead of just

`mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);`

Try this below to have it accessible.

`module.exports = {
  User : mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
}`

Comment: didn't worked :/, i have the project on github above in the link, if you can give a fast view maybe it is easier to detect issues, :/ thanks anyway